# Can I travel to Morocco on a passport that expires in 4 months?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, cruising, morocco

I'm going on a cruise that sails from Barcelona to Casablanca to Lisbon, but my US passport expires 4 months from the date of arrival. I have been unable to determine if the entry requirements for Morocco are "[valid for 3 months](https://visaguide.world/tips/passport-6-month-rule/)" or "[valid for 6 months](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Morocco.html)".

Schengen areas (Spain and Portugal) appear fine with expirations greater than 3 months from arrival, so I'm safe there.

I'm also not sure if cruise passengers are subject to the same level of passport scrutiny as air travelers (e.g. does every shore excursion require passing through customs and border control?)

Will I have any trouble with my passport on this itinerary?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, you're right. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: According to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of my country of citizenship, foreign nationals entering Morocco must possess a passport valid for no less than 6 months after their arrival date.